# rsync passing source from csv file

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to use rsync to synchronise remote files  with local server.
    It  works great but I want to do it on multiple remote servers to sync with on daily basis.

```
lanein2@FTP-Stager:/home/toor$ sshpass -p "xyz" rsync -avz lanein1@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:BrandStIN/ /home/lanein2/BrandStIN/
lanein2@FTP-Stager:/home/toor$ sshpass -p "xyz" rsync -avz lanein1@yy.yyy.yyy.yyy:Brand1/ /home/lanein2/Brand1/
lanein2@FTP-Stager:/home/toor$ sshpass -p "xyz" rsync -avz lanein1@aa.aaa.aaa.aaa:Brand1/ /home/lanein2/Brand1/
```

I want to have all ip adresses with their password  in a csv file and want to run rsync .
how can I pass a csv file data and do rsync in  a cron job.

Comment: Download the source code for `rsync` and modify it to take an input CSV file and use it in the way you want it to. Or, alternatively, write a script that reads your CSV file and generates and runs the appropriate `rsync` commands for you... I would highly recommend the alternative...

Answer (score 0):

try with a bash script, like this one (not working as it is, just a starting point)

```
#!/bin/bash

# define password for each of the servers, maybe use arrays or something like that
# also, define paths for each server (if they change)

for i in 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2; do 
# here too, you can use an array for ip addresses
  sshpass -p $PASSWORD_OF_SERVER_1 rsync -avz lanein1@$i:$SERVER1_PATH/ /home/lanein2/$SERVER1_PATH/
done
```

then reference it with cron (e.g. put it in a line of `/etc/cron.daily`)